# How to substract between same date/time DB column in Oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle, subtraction

Oracle SQL In the table there are status given to the each row(arrived, ExamCompleted, VitalsTaken, discharged...)where we track information about patients in the hospital. It is required to find the number of hours patient spent inside the hospital. How can I substract one column with itself where status are different.

```
patient_id     |      status         |  created_on
7654           |      arrived        |  2022-09-18 07:22:46
7654           |    examCompleted    |  2022-09-18 09:35:26
7654           |      vitalsTaken    |  2022-09-20 02:41:55
7654           |      discharged     |  2022-09-20 07:42:33
```

I need to substract arrived status date/time from discharged status date/time Table have many other columns but these are the ones I need to work with. If there are null recorded for a created_on column (for few rows) how can I ignore that particular row while showing data.

Desired result is something like

```
patient_id     |         timeSpent
7654           |         48:19:13
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a self join on the database table. The total time would be the value of column CREATED_ON when the STATUS is *discharged* minus the value of CREATED_ON when the STATUS is *arrived* for a given PATIENT_ID. The below SQL gives the result as a number of hours.

```sql
select A.PATIENT_ID
      ,(B.CREATED_ON - A.CREATED_ON) * 24 as STAY
  from PATIENTS A
  join PATIENTS B
    on A.PATIENT_ID = B.PATIENT_ID
 where A.STATUS = 'arrived'
   and B.STATUS = 'discharged'
```

Refer to this [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/q1loQCUq)
Also refer to: https://asktom.oracle.com/Misc/DateDiff.html

Comment: This works only if a patient comes only once forever at the hospital...
To have a correct solution you have to take into account multiple visits per patient, and don't forget you may have patients where "arrived" and "discharged" are not even the same day... (e.g. quality of sleep exam), or patient coming once in the morning, once in the afternoon, so forget about grouping by "arrived" and "discharged" the same day.
You should start by making a full set of test data covering all situations.

Comment: Note that a "visit_id" in your model, will make the solution easier and allow interleaving of visits, situation that may happen in real life. (you will have to better define the "time spent" because then time spent in exam <> time spent physically in the hospital)

Comment: @p3consulting Many thanks but I am using visit ID instead of patient ID just for the simplicity of explaining I added it as the patient ID.

Answer (score 0):

Correct?? That what you expected?

```
SELECT DISTINCT patient_id,
                MAX(created_on) OVER(PARTITION BY patient_id) - MIN(created_on) OVER(PARTITION BY patient_id)
  FROM PATIENTS
```